# NSDate formatter возвращает nil?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

**Проблема**:возвращает пустоту(т.е переходит к else), хотя до if let проверил createdDate на содержимое - print(self.createdDate)
[image: Наглядный скриншот]

Comment: можно код не скрином

Comment: Извините за мой ужасный код,я студент прохожу практику на предприятии в котором нету iOS- разработчиков, соответственно не кому мне дать совет по поводу учебных материалов.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko  
github.com/gemcave/NextAutoOrder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `dateFormatter` формат указан неправлиьно. Вот так должно работать:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Желаю успехов вашим приложениям.